# Django REST Framework: integer fields default value not showing up in browseable API form

Tags: django-rest-framework

Using django 1.6 and rest framework 2.3.13

In model class:

```
class A(models.Model):
    some_name = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=15)
```

In serilizer:

```
class ASerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = (  'some_name'  )
```

In view:

```
class AViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = A.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ASerializer
```

But in the api form, it's showing as 0, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved by adding

```
if obj is None and self.default is not None:
    return self.default
```

to rest_framework/fields.py

Original pull request:
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1248/files